# built in command to change prompt in custom linux/unix shell

Tags: c, shell, prompt

I have looked all over google and I find how to change in the bash config files, but my project requires a built in command to change the prompt.

I declared char pointer outside any function, my command modifies it, but when the function returns (int to continue a do while loop) and the prompt is displayed again, it is blank.

I have tried using a structure, union, and even a second char pointer and got the same issue.

I thought using a global char pointer that could be accessed and modified in any function would be the solution to this part of my project.

I would appreciate and will try any response.

Edit:
posted on my phone, tried to ask w/o code, but here it is
Code:

```
char *prmpt;

...
int main(int argc, char **argv)
prmpt="$$ ";
do
{
printf("%s ", prmpt);

}while(1)

int cmd_prompt(char **args)
{
 prmpt = (char*)args[1];
 return 1;
}
```

Comment: If the shell is "custom" because *you* implemented it, then *you* are the one writing *anything* to standard output, which definitely also *includes* the prompt-string. So its *you* to write the "build in" command you are looking for. Do you dare to show us what you wrote so far?

Comment: Yes, but the issue is my command should change the prompt string, I.e. "prompt %%" should execute then the following prompt should be "%% " and wait for my next command, but it executes and I get " " for my next prompt

Comment: Which function do you use to write/print out the prompt?

Comment: Printf("%s ", prmpt);  prmpt is my char pointer, it gets changed fine in the prompt change function, but when it returns the new prompt is blank

Comment: Without code, this isn't a question that can be answered..

Comment: Ok, so now please show all the relevant code. This is not a guessing game. It is for example essential to know how `prmpt` is defined and intialised.

Comment: In general programmers are no clairvoyant. In order to see a problem with a piece of code they, as a rule, need to see that piece of code.

Comment: Ok, I added the code that pertains to my prompt string, I hate typing code out on my phone

Comment: @BubbaDoe then wait until you have access to a PC. This is still very incomplete, but from what it looks like, does `cmd_prompt()` run in a *different process* than `main()`? If so, how should it be able to change a variable in a different process? (This is why *real* shells use an *environment variable* for the prompt format ...)

Comment: I'll wait until I get to a pc and post the code. It doesn't look like it hits a fork, so it should be the same process running it.

Comment: @FelixPalmen thanks for mentioning enviroment variables, im new to c programming,  using that worked perfectly, thanks

Comment: Being "*new*" to C you might like to have a look how "string"s are implemented in C, as there is no native "string" type, but only `0`-terminated `char`-arrays. This might be different from what you are used to so far.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially one needs to use `fgets` or `getline` or better yet they might use `readline` or `editline`. Here is an example using `getline`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *prompt;
    size_t len = 256;
    size_t i = 0;

    if (!(prompt = malloc(256 * sizeof(char))))
        return 1;
    strcpy(prompt, "$");

    while ( 1 )
    {
        printf("[[%s]] ", prompt);
        i = getline(&prompt, &len, stdin);
        prompt[i-1] = '\0';

    }
}
```

Or if you might try implementing `getline` on your own using `getchar` ( perhaps if getline is not available on your system, or you just want to know how it works). And eventually move on to writing your own `editline` library if you continue to be interested in writing shells.